# How to properly deal with scope in typescript

Tags: scope, typescript, angular

I have a question about context. What is to proper way to deal with context in typescript? If I understand it correctly I have a problem with closures? When I'm calling a function inside a function, which is in object (class) then it's a closure right?

But do I have to use `self = this` or is there a better way in typescript please? Because I really don't like this solution. And I don't want to bind every little thing.

Example of what I'm tolkien about:

```
export class SomeClass {
    private declaration;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(){
        var self = this;
        some code
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            self.someFunction();
        }, 1000);        
    }

    someFunction() {
      something
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can use the [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) syntax, which will capture the value of `this` to refer to the class prototype as you would expect:

```
ngOnInit() {
    some code
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.someFunction();
    }, 1000);        
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I don't know how could I not think of this. And it's so elegant! I'll leave this open for a while just to see if there is any other alternative. But thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the arrow function you can use the [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
ngOnInit(){
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        this.someFunction();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

or as @IgorRaush stated, this is more elegant:

```
ngOnInit(){
    var interval = setInterval(this.someFunction.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Which I prefer in some cases.

Comment: The way you've written it, `bind()` is useless. Change the `self` to `this` or, even better, use `setInterval(this.someFunction.bind(this), 1000)`.

Comment: @IgorRaush you're right, I copied/pasted and did not notice the use of `self` there

Comment: Thank you. I use bind, but mostly when I'm using a "controller". By that I mean a situation where I need to call a function of nested component in the "parent" component. In those cases when I need to save the context I do use bind. But I would prefer if I wouldn't have to use bind for the functions in the same component. It just seems weird to me. But please, tell me if that's a wrong thinking. I'm relatively new to angular2, I've worked with angularjs only for few weeks and didn't understand a thing, I'm a bad coder and stupid being, so I'm open to any advice. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with angular (which I've never used myself) but to javascript.  The arrow function is very useful in some situations and the bind can be more useful in others. In your example for instance, I'd use bind because it creates less code and more elegant. But maybe you just gave an example to show your scenario but in your real code it's more complex.