# this.state undefined in a method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom component that requires access to one of my actual component state (rows).
I defined it in my constructor but when it should be rendered, this.state seems to be always empty, and i dont know why...

The console always displays "undefined this.state".

Here is my code :

```
export class TableContainer extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props : any, context: any) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = { 
            rows:[ 
                { id: 1, title: 'John', count: 32 },
                { id: 2, title: 'Carl', count: 18 },
                { id: 3, title: 'Mike', count: 25 }
            ]
        };
    }

    rowGetter(i: number) {
        if(this.state) {
            console.log('defined this.state');
            return this.state.rows[i];
        }
        else {
            console.log('undefined this.state');
            return {};
        }
    }

    render() {
        return  (
            <div id="events-container">
                <ReactDataGrid
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
                    rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
                    minHeight={500} 
                />
            </div>
        );
    }    
}
```

I'm new in react so probably it's a little mistake. 
I have to precise that rowsCount get the good "this.state.rows.length" in the render function.

Thank you by advance

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876105/how-to-properly-deal-with-scope-in-typescript

Answer (score 3):

In this expression `rowGetter={this.rowGetter}` you are passing your method to `ReactDataGrid` component.
Then it calls `rowGetter` internally and javascript functions work in such way, that this function `this` linked to calling object.
It means that you have to bind your `rowGetter` method somehow to your component instance in order to have `this` linked to it.

There are several approaches:

- Direct `{this.rowGetter.bind(this)}` - lacks efficiency as it creates function every time
- `this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this)` in constructor - verbose way
- you can rewrite `rowGetter` method as an arrow function - I think it's the best approach here. It can look like this:

```js
rowGetter = (i: number) => {
  if(this.state) {
    console.log('defined this.state');
    return this.state.rows[i];
  }
  else {
    console.log('undefined this.state');
    return {};
  }
}
```

Now `this` linked to parent context and this is your component instance - precisely what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The function is being called from another context. You shoud `bind` function to the correct context:

```
rowGetter={this.rowGetter.bind(this)}
```

or declare the function via "fat arrow":

```
rowGetter = (i: number) => {
    if(this.state) {
        console.log('defined this.state');
        return this.state.rows[i];
    }
    else {
        console.log('undefined this.state');
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !!

Comment: So many duplicates on Stackoverflow  onn this question, you can just mark it a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind you method to this in you constructor:

```
    constructor(props : any, context: any) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = { 
            rows:[ 
                { id: 1, title: 'John', count: 32 },
                { id: 2, title: 'Carl', count: 18 },
                { id: 3, title: 'Mike', count: 25 }
            ]
        };
this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 choose.

1. Use bind(this)

   ```
   this.rowGetter.bind(this)
   ```

2.Use arrow-function then you don't want to use ***bind***